# React Navigation - RootStackParamList is in error in VSCode

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, navigation, expo

I started an application managed by Expo and installed the navigation dependencies.

I chose to use Typescript and therefore followed the typing recommendations in the documentation. I attach to this request the 3 main files.

This application **works fine**, however, in 'Screen' files the call to 'RootStackParamList' **is in error** according **to VSCode**.

I therefore allow myself to post on Stack **before sending a ticket to Microsoft**. Is this error **legitimate or** do I need to initiate a ticket with Microsoft support to let them know?

**Thank you** in advance

**App.tsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './src/screens/SettingsScreen';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined,
  Settings: undefined; 
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: "Accueil" }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ title: "Paramètres" }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**./src/screens/HomeScreen.tsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// #region typage
type ProfileScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList, // VSCode Error: Cannot find name 'RootStackParamList'
  'Home'
>;

type Props = {
  navigation: ProfileScreenNavigationProp;
};
//#endregion

function HomeScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Paramètres"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')} 
           />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });

export default HomeScreen;
```

**./src/screens/SettingsScreen.tsx**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// #region typage
type ProfileScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList, // VSCode Error: Cannot find name 'RootStackParamList'
  'Home'
>;

type Props = {
  navigation: ProfileScreenNavigationProp;
};
//#endregion

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }: Props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Settings Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });

export default SettingsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use an other file for RootStackParamList and import with :

```js
import { RootStackParamList } from '../types/RootStackParams';
```

RootStackParams.tsx

```js
export type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined,
    Settings: { itemId: number, otherParams: string}; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the `RootStackParamList` was not exported from `App.tsx`, and then imported into the screens.

In `App.tsx`, add `export`:

```js
export type RootStackParamList = { 
   Home: undefined,
   Settings: undefined; 
};
```

In `HomeScreen` and `SettingsScreen`, add import statement and import the type from `App.tsx`:

```js
import { RootStackParamList } from './App';
```

I personally prefer to save the `RootStackParamList` in another file (follow Moltroon's answer) so it's separated from other files, and import the type wherever it's needed.